# VBA Conditional formatting based on value in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a validation that checks if NZD is found in a certain column (T) then a validation message is printed. This works however I am trying to add another conditional to it, that the value of the cell 6 cells to the right (column Z) has to be "3" also. I have tried `And cell.Offset.Value(0, 6) = "3" Then` but this isn't correct. Any idea?

```
Sub checkforNZD()
Sheets("xxx").Activate
For Each cell In Range("T2:T" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    If cell.Value = "NZD" And cell.Offset.Value(0, 6) = "3" Then
    cell.Offset(0, -18).Value = "XXX"
    cell.Offset(0, -19).Value = "NZD"
    End If
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: How is it "not correct"?

Comment: I get an error on line ```if cell.value = "NZD"...``` But if I remove the ```And cell.Offset.Value(0, 6) = "3" ``` then the code runs

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: `cell.Offset(0,6).Value`. Got the order mixed up.